# Electret condenser microphone, LM386 amplification... does size matter?

Tags: amplifier, microphone, lm386

I've built a motorcycle intercom, of which comprises of two amp units, one for the rider, one for the pillion. Both are powered by a 9v battery each, and the option (using a jumper) to enable boost.

The problem we're having is that they're very quiet... not ideal on a motorcycle. When I enable the boost on the LM386 (0.1µF cap, pin 1-8) the sound quality is distorted beyond an acceptable level.

**My question is, does the size of the electret condenser mic make a difference to the input of the amp, and thus the volume (or quality) of the output? If so, any pointers on what I should be looking for?**

I don't have any specs on the microphones I'm using, but here's a picture. It's about 5mm wide, as you can see:

[image]

If it helps, here is my amp unit schematic:

[image]

- please excuse my schematic skills... I think it's right

Comment: It may be that the gain ends up being too high and distorts. Looking at http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm386.pdf it shows putting a 1.2K and 10uF in series between pins 1 & 8 for a gain of 50 instead of 200 (disonnected is 20). Maybe try playing around with a few different resistor values. Hard to know without a datasheet, but some of those small electret mics are very sensitive. Also what impedance are the speakers? If headphones they may have too high an impedance to give much output power.

Comment: Interesting idea, my gain is controlled by a jumper, not a push button as the schematic says... so it shouldn't be too difficult to experiment with different gain levels. Thanks :-)

Comment: @PeterJ Just a follow up, I slapped a 10k pot over the boost (pre-set to 1.2k) and you're right, it did improve the sound quality. I'll let you know how I get on from here.

Comment: I would suspect: bigger size, more bass response.